# SQL Dependency dependency_OnChange fires even if there is no change in record

Tags: c#, sql, sqldependency

I am using SQL Dependency to update dashoboard when there is change in SQL DB table.
below method I am calling from Global.asax file in app_start() event.

```
public void InitialiseMetricsDependency()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
            {

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [id],[Application],[customerName],[Actual] FROM [dbo].[Metrics]", connection))
                {
                    command.Notification = null;

                    dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += dependency_OnChange;
                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex.InnerException.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Now I have below dependency_OnChange event

```
private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
                {

                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                      using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [id],[Application],[customerName],[Actual] FROM [dbo].[Metrics]", connection))
                    {
                        command.Notification = null;

                        dependency = new SqlDependency(command);

                        dependency.OnChange += dependency_OnChange;
                        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                            connection.Open();

                        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    }
                }

               //push data to client
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex.InnerException.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

I am updating Metrics table by other API's, So Api run and it update every row in Metircs table. So for every row on_change event is fires. 
**If API value and existing row value is same still dependency_OnChange event is fire**

How can I fire dependency_OnChange event only if value is really change ?